# How to make NUnit Console Runner print test names

Tags: nunit

The NUnit console runner only prints to the console when a test causes something to be printed.

Is there a way to make it print every test name? Something similar to mocha, shown below.

[image: mocha tests]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `--labels` option.

There are various options for the level of output, `on`, `off` or `all` - and with v3.6, which will be released soon, there will also be `before` and `after`.

To match your picture, `on` is probably suitable.

```
--labels=on
```

Comment: Found that I had to use `all`

Comment: With v3.16.3 --labels=on is deprecated, now you can use --labels=OnOutputOnly